# How to create highlight around ion-avatar that indicates that it has been clicked?

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic5 Angular and I would like to create a highlight around ion-avatar when the user clicked on it and will be disappeared if the user clicked on it again.

[image]
Users can click on each image (one at a time) and there will be a highlight around the image.

HTML:

```
<ion-card class="scrolling-wrapper">
          <div class="item" *ngFor="let item of list">
              <ion-avatar>
              <img [src]= "source to image" >
            </ion-avatar>
          </div>
</ion-card>
```

SCSS:

```
.scrolling-wrapper {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

  .item {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 4px;
  }
}
```

Comment: need more detials .. at least share your html code how you have added class to this section and how you click on this ..so that we can replicate this at our end .. suggest you answer

Comment: I've added more details :)

Comment: hows your click function

Comment: I've implemented the answer below to my code. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to proceed like this:

1. Declare an empty variable (example: highlightedAvatar = "";)
2. Capture the id of the clicked item from the .html
3. If your variable has a value, you empty it, otherwise you assign the id
4. create the styles you want to add to the .css (e.g. brightness...)
5. Load the css class with a condition

You seriously need to provide some code so you can understand exactly the procedure

**Edit:**

**HTML:**

```
<ion-card class="scrolling-wrapper">
          <div class="item" *ngFor="let item of list">
              <ion-avatar [class.highlighted]="highlighted == item.id" (click)="selectAvatar(item.id)">
              <img [src]= "source to image" >
            </ion-avatar>
          </div>
</ion-card>
```

**TS:**

```
 export class AppComponent{
         highlighted = "";
    ...
    selectAvatar(id){
  if (this.highlighted === "") {
    this.highlighted = id;
  } else {
    this.highlighted = "";
  }
}
```

**SCSS:**

```
.highlighted{
filter: brightness(120%);
}
```

Of course you can toy around with the css to style your way of highlighting